# Loading JSP page in segments using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, asynchronous

I have a jsp that take input from textarea and store it into an array. I have another class, ProcessData.jsp, which takes input from "name" parameter, process it and return result in form of table.

What I want is to iterate over the array, take element, send it to ProcessData.jsp, take output and append it after previous results.

```
<%   
for(int i=0; i<list.length; i++){
  String elementFromList=list[i].trim();
  // Send it to ProcessData.jsp and print result here         
}
%>
```

When I try to run my existing code, it loads everything at-once but I want every element to load asynchronously i.e. take first element from array, process it and display it, then 2nd and 3rd, so on...

Jquery can do the trick but I just don't know how to reach there. Like calling jquery function in loop with input or iterate over the list in a different way.

Any help is appreciated.